# themes diabled after core update

Tags: 7, theming, updating

Every time we update Drupal core our custom themes, all previously enabled and one set to default, are no longer enabled. Has anyone else experienced this or know why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://drupal.org/node/305653) in Drupal core for 6.x and 7.x